# Can I use pure grpc (not grpc-web) in frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, grpc, grpc-web

According to https://grpc.io/blog/state-of-grpc-web/

> It is currently impossible to implement the HTTP/2 gRPC spec3 in the browser, as there is simply no browser API with enough fine-grained control over the requests. For example: there is no way to force the use of HTTP/2, and even if there was, raw HTTP/2 frames are inaccessible in browsers.

However [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=http2) says most of the browsers have http/2 implementation.

Is it still impossible to use pure grpc in frontend javascript? If it is, why?

Answer (score 2):

As that caniuse page shows, browsers are able to communicate with HTTP/2 servers. But the gRPC protocol does not just use the HTTP/2 protocol, it uses HTTP/2 in a specific way. The problem is that browsers do not provide the JavaScript APIs that are necessary to control the use of HTTP/2 in the ways that are required by the gRPC specification. In particular, trailers are an important part of the gRPC protocol, and they are not generally accessible in browser HTTP/2 APIs.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Is there any documentation explaining about it?